# Where Do I get Source package for Perf tool

Tags: linux, source, perf-event, perf

I am looking for source package of perf tool ,which I wanted to compile for ARM
Linux ,I have already set up the cross compile tool chain.

I have compiled the the oprofile and got it source(Oprofile-0.9.8.tar.bz2) from sourceforge.net.

Can anyone point me to perf tool source ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source code for `perf` is included in the [Linux kernel source tree](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/) under `tools/perf`.

Comment: Thanks Thomas but I can get this source in tar.bz2 format because my build infrastructure will automatically fetch this source from some repository like for Oprofile it fetched from sourceforge.net

Comment: Sure, you can get either xz or bz2 compressed patches or tarballs of the complete kernel source at [kernel.org](http://www.kernel.org/), or you could use the kernel sources provided by your target distribution (if there is one).